# How do you tell someone who's asking you for directions, in a single sentence, that they could follow you since you're headed in the same direction?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-usage

What is the proper sentence to use when you're trying to tell the person asking for directions that they could follow you **because the way you're headed largely overlaps with theirs** (I'm particularly keen on an emphasis on this in the sentence of interest)?

I myself thought of:

> "Why don't you follow me, since I'm going part of the way in."

but since I've never really heard anybody use this before, I'm not even sure if it means what I'm looking for.

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Comment: "I'm going that way; just follow me." Then when your ways part, give directions.

Comment: Your own example is nearly perfect as it is - just missing a question mark at the end, instead of the full-stop.  'there' would be more appropriate than 'in' (at the end) in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

> - I'm going that way; just follow me.
> - I'm headed in that direction, follow me as far as 10th street.
> - I'm going to X, you could follow me as far as Y.